# Unable to connect to oracle database from groovy

Tags: jdbc, groovy, groovy-console

Hi i am unable to connect to oracle database in groovy . I have used the following code in groovy console but getting the following compilation  error

```
unable to resolve class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleTypes
 at line: 5, column: 1
```

I have used the following code

```
import java.sql.Connection
import java.sql.DriverManager
import javax.sql.DataSource
import groovy.sql.Sql
import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleTypes

sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:databasename",
               "username", "password", "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver")
```

If i remove `import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleTypes` statement i am getting the following  `WARNING: Sanitizing stacktrace:`.Kindly help me how to resolve this i have place ojdbc14.jar in the lib folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove all unnecessary imports and driver class from *newInstance* call as follows:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:databasename", "username", "password")
```

The above is enough and works just fine for me, however I'm using ojdbc6-11.2.jar

Beside depends on if you are using *SID* or *service name* the last semicolon at JDBC URL might have to be changed for slash.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me to check the ';' or '/'. I had to use a '/' for my DB service name.

Answer (score 0):

I had a few issues connecting Groovy to Oracle.

I tried grabbing ojdbc14.jar using

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle/ojdbc14/10.2.0.3.0

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle/ojdbc14
@Grapes(
    @Grab(group='com.oracle', module='ojdbc14', version='10.2.0.3.0')
)
```

but it did not find the file.

I copied ojdbc14.jar from my Oracle Client Directory to %GROOVY_HOME%\lib and it worked like a charm. I am sure you can download the ojdbc14.jar from the internet if you don't have the Oracle SQL Client Installed.

copy C:\DevSuiteHome_1\jdbc\lib\ojdbc14.jar C:\groovy-2.4.11\lib

```
url= "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:SID"
username = "un"
password = "pw"
driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"

// Groovy Sql connection test
import groovy.sql.*
sql = Sql.newInstance(url, username, password, driver)
try {
    sql.eachRow('select sysdate from dual'){ row ->
    println row
 }
 } finally {
     sql.close()
 }
```

Hope that helps.