# How to define database 'driver' using Groovy sql module

Tags: groovy, database-connection, driver, oracle-sqldeveloper, classnotfoundexception

I am trying to connect to an Oracle Sql Developer DB using Groovys sql class, which requires 4 pieces of information: (db url, username, password, db driver) I have all information needed except the driver. I have tried using oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDrive and have set my GROOVY_HOME as : Variable: %GROOVY_HOME%\lib   Value: C:\Oracle_SQL_DEVELOPER\sqldeveloper

I am receiving the following error :

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

I have referenced a few answers here on StackOverflow but haven't had any luck setting up a connection. Here are the links I've read and tried:

[Unable to connect to oracle database from groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19049194/unable-to-connect-to-oracle-database-from-groovy)

[SQLException: No suitable Driver Found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/orcl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103369/sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcoraclethin-localhost1521-or)

I have also looked and researched the Groovy documentation but it is not clear on how to define the driver: https://groovy-lang.org/databases.html#_connecting_with_a_datasource

Any help would be much appreciated. Here is the code for reference:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
```

class EstablishConnection {

```
def static url = 'url'
def static user = 'user'
def static password = 'pass'
def static driver = 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver'
def static sql = Sql.newInstance(url, user, password, driver)
```

}

```
EstablishConnection.sql.eachRow('select * from ACCOUNT where CONSTI_ID = \'12345678\';'){
        row ->
            def a = row[0]
    }
```

Comment: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDrive 
First thing first - spelling. Missing an r at the end

Comment: Thanks for that catch, I created the typo copying my code into the question. I am still getting the same issue.

Comment: do you have a jdbc jar installed? if so where?

Comment: I dont have a jdbc jar installed as everything I read lead me to believe I only needed one if I was using a non oracle db..would I need a jdbc.jar regardless of db type?

Comment: I think you still need jdbc jar. Try putting these two lines at the top of your groovy file
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true)
@Grab('com.oracle:ojdbc7:12.1.0.1.0')

Comment: so I downloaded ojdbc jar version 7.1.8.0_111 and places C:\Oracle_SQL_Developer\sqldeveloper\lib and still no luck. Know if I actually need to create and define a %GROOVY_HOME% as a system variable?

Comment: did you try the Grab directives as I mentioned above? I was able to replicate your issue and in my case it works with those two lines at the top

Comment: I figured this issue out. I had to add the below line of code to the build.Gradle file. // JDBC
    compile group: 'com.oracle.weblogic', name: 'ojdbc7', version: '12.1.3-0-0'